# SQL : issue with delete query that never ends

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works fine and fast :

```
select t.id_facture from
    (SELECT distinct id_facture, num_commande 
     FROM table) t
group by t.id_facture
having count(*)>1;
```

But when I want to use it in order to delete records

```
delete from table where id_facture in (
   select t.id_facture from
       (SELECT distinct id_facture, num_commande 
         FROM table) t
   group by t.id_facture
   having count(*)>1 );
```

it lasts forever and end up with an error :

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Is there another to perform this delete query?

```
id_facture  num_commande
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           4
3           5
3           6
```

I want to delete rows with id_facture : 1 and 3 because they have differents num_commande related. id_facture 2 has only one associated num_commande, so I want to keep it.

Comment: In this case i recommend to use limit in your first subquery. The group by in select not the same as in the delete. If i understand well, you have more element with t.id_facture, and if you groupping that in select you just get 1 element with that id. But in delete when you want to delete the t.id_factur elements, you have 1 or more elements to delete.

Comment: I have posted an example of what I want, if it helps... thx.

Comment: Instead of using the slow `IN(SELECT...)` use a multi-table `DELETE` syntax with a `JOIN`.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many of those will be deleted?  And do you really want to delete all N rows whenever N>1?  Or did you want to keep one copy of each?  (To do that, there are radically different queries that work faster.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` instead of `IN()`...

```
DELETE
  example
FROM
  example
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id_facture
    FROM example
GROUP BY id_facture
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT num_commande) > 1
)
  dupes
    ON dupes.id_facture = example.id_facture
;
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b33532dc29c3f3d889890952d45f26af

Comment: And this index may help:  `INDEX(id_facture, num_commande)`

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE id_facture IN (
    SELECT id_facture
    FROM (
        SELECT t.id_facture
        FROM t
        GROUP BY t.id_facture
        HAVING MIN(t.num_commande) <> MAX(t.num_commande)
    ) AS x
)
```

Could you please try the above #TO_DELETE is your table

Comment: I am getting this error : Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table #TO_DELETE (i have replaced by my table) for update in FROM clause

Comment: Hm. Then for MySQL it is necessary to invent some other approach

Comment: @thomas the `as x` subquery should fix it

Comment: I manage to get it done with : 
delete from t 
where id_facture in (select distinct id_facture from
(SELECT ID_FACTURE  
  FROM t 
  WHERE id_facture like 'F2%'
  GROUP BY ID_FACTURE
  HAVING MIN(NUM_COMMANDE)<>MAX(NUM_COMMANDE)
  ) t );

Comment: Glad to read it :-)